# What does (Normal time-Crash time=0) implies?

Tags: scheduling, resource-planning

In Crashing a project, if for an activity [Normal time - Crash time = 0], what does it mean?
Since Crash cost per day = |(Crash cost-Normal cost)/(Normal Time- Crash time)|

The Crash cost per day becomes infinite. what does this implies?

Comment: Not entirely sure that I have enough context to understand this. If [Normal time - Crash time = 0], doesn't that mean that Normal Time == Crash Time, which would mean that the project has not been crashed?  On the other hand it may simply be that if Normal Time = Crash time, then the denominator of the crash cost/day equation is 0, the equation is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be using this as a prediction, right?  If you are predicting your normal time and your crash time are the same, as evidenced by the zero, then you are essentially predicting increased costs with no gain in days, which produces an error in the ratio.  That implies: DON'T DO IT!

Under what scenario would you try to get approved money to crash a schedule that you are predicting you cannot crash?

Answer (score 0):

Practically, this means that the project cannot be crashed. Throwing more resources at the project will not get it done faster and in fact will be wasted effort/cost.

There are a number of real-world projects in which this has been the case.  A book called "The Mythical Man-Month" would be a good way to explore this further.